# Path with spaces in Matlab error

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I'm trying to execute the below lines

```
command ='C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2010a\bin\matlab -wait -nodesktop -nosplash -r wrapper';
[status, output] = system(command);
```

but I'm getting an error saying:

```
' 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.'
```

it seems to me that the spaces are making  the error as shown from the error it only captured 'C:\Program', so can anyone please advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping the path in double quotes.. as in :

"C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB...."